# Realm DataBase file path can not be modified. Does anyone know why this is, or how to solve it?

Tags: android, database, realm

I am learning to use Realm database, I found. Realm file path can not be modified. Does anyone know why this is, or how to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean `Realm file path cannot be modified`? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the directory where your Realm is stored using https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#directory-java.io.File-. For example:

```
Realm.init(context);
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
   .directory("store/it/here")
   .name("my-realm-file")
   .build();
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```